# Create multiple sequences with different lengths (length.out)

Tags: r, vector, sequence, seq

Let's say I have a vector,

```
n <- c(1:100)
```

and I want to output multiple sequences for each value 'n' takes in the vector above.

I tried doing something like this:

```
x <- seq (0,5, length.out = n+1)
x <- x[-1]
```

I get the error:

> Warning Message:
> In seq.default(0,5, length.out = n+1)
> First element used of length.out argument

I then want to use 'x' for a calculating in:

```
fx <- dnorm(x, mean = 0 , sd = 4)
```

Where fx[1] will output the first value of fx and so on up to fx[n]

Comment: After you run `x <- seq (0,5, length.out = n+1)`, what do you expect to be in `x`? I'm not sure what you are trying to do there. Rather than `n=1:100` maybe make a smaller example and show exactly the output so you expect so possible solutions can be tested and verified.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you wanted x to look like?

```
x <- lapply(n, function(i) seq (0,5, length.out = i+1))
x
[[1]]
[1] 0 5

[[2]]
[1] 0.0 2.5 5.0

[[3]]
[1] 0.000000 1.666667 3.333333 5.000000

[[4]]
[1] 0.00 1.25 2.50 3.75 5.00

[[5]]
[1] 0 1 2 3 4 5

[[6]]
[1] 0.0000000 0.8333333 1.6666667 2.5000000 3.3333333 4.1666667 5.0000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following base R code can help

```
g <- Vectorize(function(k) seq (0,5, length.out = k+1)[-1])
x <- g(n)
fx <- sapply(x, dnorm, mean = 0,sd = 4)
```

such that

```
> head(x)
[[1]]
[1] 5

[[2]]
[1] 2.5 5.0

[[3]]
[1] 1.666667 3.333333 5.000000

[[4]]
[1] 1.25 2.50 3.75 5.00

[[5]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[6]]
[1] 0.8333333 1.6666667 2.5000000 3.3333333 4.1666667 5.0000000
```

and

```
> head(fx)
[[1]]
[1] 0.04566227

[[2]]
[1] 0.08204024 0.04566227

[[3]]
[1] 0.09144309 0.07047797 0.04566227

[[4]]
[1] 0.09498265 0.08204024 0.06426848 0.04566227

[[5]]
[1] 0.09666703 0.08801633 0.07528436 0.06049268 0.04566227

[[6]]
[1] 0.09759449 0.09144309 0.08204024 0.07047797 0.05797360 0.04566227
```