# Divide numbers into equally-spaced intervals ranging between 0-1

Tags: r, calculation

Suppose I have this series of numbers in a vector:

```
vec <- c(1,2,3,4,5)           # just an example, numbers could be far higher
```

How can I programmatically divide these numbers into equally-spaced intervals ranging between `0-1`, such that I get:

for

- 1: `0`
- 2: `0, 1`
- 3: `0, 0.5, 1`
- 4: `0, 0.33, 0.66, 1`
- 5: `0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1`
- and so on.

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe: `seq(0, 1, length.out =  5)` ? Try: `lapply(1:5, function(i) seq(0, 1, length.out =  i))`

Comment: Are you asking "how do I find the maximum, and then divide that by the number of intervals" or are you asking "does 'r' have some functionality to do this already"?

Comment: @zx8754 Why not post this as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate, can't find the correct target... posted the answer below.

Comment: Google sent me to your own old question, that has a solution with length.out :) https://stackoverflow.com/q/64078958/680068 Still can't find the correct dupe, these things are hard to google.

Comment: Related: [Create multiple sequences with different lengths (length.out)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60233452/create-multiple-sequences-with-different-lengths-length-out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use *seq* with *length.out* argument:

```
lapply(1:5, function(i) seq(0, 1, length.out =  i))
# [[1]]
# [1] 0
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 0 1
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 0.0 0.5 1.0
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.6666667 1.0000000
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 0.00 0.25 0.50 0.75 1.00
```

or *mapply*:

```
mapply(seq, from = 0, to = 1, length.out = 1:5)
```

Answer (score 1):

if I understand well maybe is somthing like this:

```
v <- 1:5
norm <- function(x){
  if(length(x)==1)0 else{
    (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))
  }
  }
lapply(v, function(x)(norm(seq(1,x,length.out = x))))
```

output

```
[[1]]
[1] 0

[[2]]
[1] 0 1

[[3]]
[1] 0.0 0.5 1.0

[[4]]
[1] 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.6666667 1.0000000

[[5]]
[1] 0.00 0.25 0.50 0.75 1.00
```

Comment: Yes, nice, but `lapply(1:5, function(i) seq(0, 1, length.out =  i))` from @zx8754 works and is more concise!

Answer (score 1):

Using `map`

```
library(purrr)
map(1:5, ~ seq(0, 1, length.out = .x))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[1] 0

[[2]]
[1] 0 1

[[3]]
[1] 0.0 0.5 1.0

[[4]]
[1] 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.6666667 1.0000000

[[5]]
[1] 0.00 0.25 0.50 0.75 1.00
```